# Use feature toggle in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I pretend to use feature toggle within Lambda and API Gateway to enable/disable aditional features in my application.

But I have a concern: If I add a lot of toggles in my Lambda, when I compile, it will always compile for all code, even if my feature is disabled ?

In this way, the end result of lambda always will be a build with a lot of code that I won't use? Is this has any impact in the cold start of the Lambda? Is there a way to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will ship “code that isn’t used”, but you’d have to have A LOT of this conditional code to see an impact on your cold start time.

You can compare the size of the compiled code with/without the feature flags. However, I think your start time will include more nuisances than just the size of your binaries.
From my experience what your function initializes on start usually has a greater impact.